# Submitting Rails form with AJAX and Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm trying to make some AJAX magic to a simple form using Coffeescript.

My form is as following, got the remote: true part working:

```
<%= simple_form_for :contributions, :url => url_for(:action => "create", :controller => "contributions"), :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :name, placeholder: "Name", hint: false, label: false, input_html: { class: "form-control" }, wrapper_html: { class: "form-group" } %>
        <%= f.input :amount, placeholder: "Amount", hint: false, label: false, input_html: { class: "form-control" }, wrapper_html: { class: "form-group" } %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, :value => @event.id %>
        <%= f.button :submit, "Save" %>
    <% end %>
```

How would I handle this with Coffeescript?

Thanks